# Show shopify inventory stock location

Tags: shopify

Shopify introduced a new feature of adding multiple locations. For example, you have **Product A**, and have a stock of **3 at Location X** and **2 at Location Y**.

How can I show this information in the product page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I literally finished the exact app @David Lazar described here (because I needed it, I just found this post afterwards)

Demo: https://shipping-demo.myshopify.com/products/test-product

**You can install the app here:**
http://inventorylocations.checkmyapp.net

It will install the script that will fetch the data.

For now you need to add this to the **product-template.liquid** (where you want the numbers to show up):

```
<div id="inventoryLocationInformation">
        <strong>Inventory:</strong><br />
        <span class="inventoryLocationLoading">Loading..</span>
      </div>
```

For now it caches the product information for 1 minute, I might make it 2, or I might make it configurable in the backend soon (1,2,5,10) to keep performance up to par.

In the backend you can set which locations to show on the frontend (if you have some warehouse for instance, you don't want to show it)

some more information:
https://www.thomaslang.nl/shopify-show-product-inventory-location-frontend/

Comment: Note that one big risk to this is that just because you can show off where variants are located (the only reason to do this), you might confuse the customer big time as fulfillment then becomes the next issue. You might "have" some inventory but that does not mean "this" customer can buy it, at least not without screwing with fulfillment in ways that may or may not lose you money. 

It does reveal a question to as to why Shopify has yet to open up Inventory Levels to front-end Liquid. At that point, this pattern is not needed anymore.

Comment: Correct, I also added the option to hide certain locations, which can be extra confusing if no inventory is in a brick and mortar store for instance, and the warehouse is hidden, it might look like no inventory is available.. 

but these are edge cases..on the forums shopify told that it would become available in the liquid, but that was 8 monthts ago.. so I decided to just create this for my customer for now, and see how long it takes to get sorted.

any ideas are always welcome!

Comment: Multi-Location was launched without much concern for the actual use or implications. I too am waiting a year now for Liquid to catch up... I guess it goes to show how hurry up and wait is the norm :)

Answer (score 1):

One for sure way would be to install an App in your shop that has API access granted to Inventory Level and Locations. With that, you could make an App Proxy call using Ajax on the front-end the customer is using to ask for the locations and stock level at each. Then you could ask the API for the answer, and show it.

The customer would still not be able to easily ask for product A from location XYZ versus location ZYX but they would know things exist anyway.

Someone else may have a better idea but this one is 100% certain to work for you.

Comment: that's a great idea, and I had the same great idea! (albeit a few months later :) )  (see my answer below)